# Depth of a pipeline in a CPU's architecture

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu-pipelines, cpu

I follow a course on CPU architectures and I'm making exercises at the moment. Now I encountered the word "depth of a pipeline" in one of the exercises, but I don't know what's meant by the depth of a pipeline. Is it the number of stages of the pipeline or something else? I can't find it anywhere in the syllabus.

Comment: Yes, it is the number of stages in the pipeline (though usually one is more interested in the number of stages until a branch is resolved).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that depth is a measure of the overlapping of instructions while number of stages is a hardware constant. When you increase the number of stages, you usually make the CPU faster but it is with dimishing margin. See [Almdahl's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) about this and the book ["Computer Organization and Design" by Pattersson and Hennesay](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0124077269).

[image]

The more stages, the larger the depth but it is stated that there can be optimal number of stages or optimal depth:

According to (M.S. Hrishikeshi et. al. the 29th International Symposium on Computer Architecture)

> The difference between pipeline depth and pipeline stages; is the
>   Optimal Logic Depth Per Pipeline Stage which about is 6 to 8 FO4
>   Inverter Delays. In that, by decreasing the amount of logic per
>   pipeline stage increases pipeline depth, which in turn reduces IPC due
>   to increased branch misprediction penalties and functional unit
>   latencies. In addition, reducing the amount of logic per pipeline
>   stage reduces the amount of useful work per cycle while not affecting
>   overheads associated with latches, clock skew and jitter. Therefore,
>   shorter pipeline stages cause the overhead to become a greater
>   fraction of the clock period, which reduces the effective frequency
>   gains.

Comment: Thank you! It's a little more complicated than I thought...

Comment: @PieterVerschaffelt yes, it is possible with a situation where you increase the number of stages while depth doesn't increase, so they are not exactly the same measure. There is not much documentation about it.